# unable to inflate fragment when initializing a View from activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am fiddling with kotlin for the first time and I have found that whenener I try to initialize a fragment on the main view it throws an exception when it loads

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.firstapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.firstapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.example.firstapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.example.firstapplication:id/main_navigation

line 59 has

```
  app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation"
```

main_fragment.kt

```kotlin
    package com.example.firstapplication
    
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.TextView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.core.view.isVisible
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.action_bar.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.*
    
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
    private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"
    
    /**
     * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
     * Use the [main_fragment.newInstance] factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    class main_fragment : Fragment() {
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private var param1: String? = null
        private var param2: String? = null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            arguments?.let {
                param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
                param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
            }
            var buttonClickChangeText: Button = getView()?.findViewById(R.id.buttonClickChangeText) as Button
            var textView: TextView = getView()?.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
            var datePickedText: EditText = getView()?.findViewById(R.id.datePickedText) as EditText
            //var textView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
            var clickCounter:Int=0
            buttonClickChangeText.setOnClickListener{
                clickCounter++
                //clickDatePicker(it)
                if(ContainsNoLetters(datePickedText.text.toString()))
                {
                    /*if(IsDate(datePickedText.text.toString()))*/
    
                    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    val day:Int=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    val month:Int =(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ 1)
                    val year:Int =calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                    var dayStr:String=if(day.toString().length==1) "0${day}" else day.toString()
                    var monthStr:String=if(month.toString().length==1) "0${month}" else month.toString()
    
                    //val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("\"dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US)
                    //val birthday = LocalDate.parse("${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${year}", formatter)
    
                    val todayDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${year}")
                    val birthday = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(datePickedText.text.toString())
                    val difference =((todayDate.getTime()/1000)- (birthday.getTime()/1000)) + 7200
    
                    //val currentDate:Date= sdf.format()
                    textView.text = "Desde ${datePickedText.text} han pasado\n" +
                            "$difference segundos  o ${difference/60} minutos o\n${(difference/60)/60} horas  o ${((difference/60)/60)/24} dias"
    
    
                }
    
                //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                buttonClickChangeText.isVisible=false
                datePickedText.isVisible= false
            }
    
            datePickedText.setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
                if(b)selDate(view)
            })
            imageMenu.setOnClickListener({
                navigationsidemenu.isVisible=!navigationsidemenu.isVisible
            })
    
    
        }
    
        fun IsDate(str: String):Boolean{
            return str.contains("^(?:(?:31(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})\$|^(?:29(\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))\$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})\$")
        }
        fun ContainsNoLetters(str:String):Boolean
        {
            return !str.contains("[a-zA-Z]+")
        }
        fun selDate(view:View){
            var datePickedText:TextView? = getView()?.findViewById(R.id.datePickedText)
            var calendar:Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            var day:Int = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            var month:Int =calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            var year:Int= calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            DatePickerDialog(view.context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, y, m, d->
                month=m;
                day=d;
                year=y;
                month+=1;
    
                var dayStr:String=if(day.toString().length==1) "0${day}" else day.toString()
                var monthStr:String=if(month.toString().length==1) "0${month}" else month.toString()
                //Toast.makeText(this,"${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${year}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                datePickedText?.setText("${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${year}")
            },year,month,day).show()
            var dayStr:String=if(day.toString().length==1) "0${day}" else day.toString()
            month+=1;
            var monthStr:String=if(month.toString().length==1) "0${month}" else month.toString()
    //      var  yearStr:String=if(year.toString().length==2) "20${year}" else year.toString()
            var date:Date? =SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${year}");
    
    
            datePickedText?.clearFocus()
        }
        fun clickDatePicker(view:View ){
            var selectedDay:Int;var selectedMonth:Int;var selectedYear:Int;
            val calendar: Calendar=Calendar.getInstance()
            val day:Int =calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            val month:Int =calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val year:Int =calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            DatePickerDialog(view.context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
                    datePicker, y, m, d-> selectedYear =y; selectedDay=d; selectedMonth=m;
              //  Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"SELECTED: ${y}/${m}/${d}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            },year,month,day).show()
    
        }
    
    
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout._main_fragment, container, false)
        }
    
        companion object {
            /**
             * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
             * this fragment using the provided parameters.
             *
             * @param param1 Parameter 1.
             * @param param2 Parameter 2.
             * @return A new instance of fragment main_fragment.
             */
            // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
            @JvmStatic
            fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                main_fragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

main_fragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        tools:context=".main_fragment">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:name="com.example.firstapplication.textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:text="Texto"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
    
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClickChangeText"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:gravity="clip_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="564dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Calc"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/datePickedText"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:ems="5"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="dd-mm-yyyy"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </FrameLayout>
```

```xml
  

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:startDestination="@layout/_main_fragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation">
```

and main_navigation has the following code

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/_main_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.firstapplication.main_fragment" android:label="_main_fragment">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/_profile_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.firstapplication.profile_fragment" android:label="_profile_fragment">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/notificationFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/_notification_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.firstapplication.profile_fragment" android:label="_notification_fragment">
    </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/_settings_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.firstapplication.profile_fragment" android:label="@string/hello_settings_fragment">
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

and MainActivity

```kotlin
 

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

try{
    var navController: NavController = navigationsidemenu.findNavController()
    var navigationsidemenu: NavigationView =findViewById(R.id.navigationsidemenu)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationsidemenu,navController)

}catch(Ex:Exception)
{
    println(Ex.message)
    print(Ex.localizedMessage)
}

}
```

So I wonder wha I could I be doing possibly wrong?

Thank you and I really appreaciate helping me with this as I am novice in kotlin

Comment: The problem occurs in MainFragment, please show the code

Comment: @GHH I have copied the main?fragment.xml content  at the beginning but i dont know I thought it would be an issue with the  main actibity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your start destination in you main_navigation.xml?
add this **app:startDestination="@id/yourStartDestinationFragmentId"** to Your main_navigation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/yourStartDestinationFragmentId"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation">
```

Comment: in ```xml<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:startDestination="@layout/_main_fragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation">

    </fragment>```

Comment: remove from this, and add it to your main_navigation.xml

Comment: it is better to change fragment to fragmentContainerView, navigation component parse navGraph xml file, if cant find startDestination it will produce some error, with your navigation controller, you can change the view if it define in your nav graph xml file

Comment: I will try that